# how to generate the POI excel file in a specific location?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a java maven programme that generate an excel file using Apache POI API, all is working correctly but when i try to put the report to a specific location doing like this
 : `FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\C5292600\\Desktop\\report1.xlsx"));` 
i get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid char (:) found at index (1) in sheet name 'C:\Users\C5292600\Desktop\repor'
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.WorkbookUtil.validateSheetName(WorkbookUtil.java:151)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:873)
    at com.occCheckNoData.report.Create.newSheet(Create.java:25)
    at com.occCheckNoData.report.mainReport.main(mainReport.java:34)
```

Comment: Are you putting the file name as sheet name in the excel?

Comment: The exception does not match the line of code you gave

Comment: yes problem solved,  i puted a path here : XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("report1.xlsx"); thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Is it an existing path? If not use something like `File file = new File(yourpath); file.mkdirs();` to create a new path. And to generate the file `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(yourpath + filetype));`

Comment: problem solved, i puted a path here : XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("report1.xlsx"); now i fixed it thank you for the support.